# Google Chart IE does not understand string Date Fomat

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, google-visualization

I have one application that creates google chart from dynamic data, so when i pass row data in form of

```
$scope.chartObject.data = {
        "cols": cols,
        "rows": [{ "c": [{ "v": "Date(2017, 1, 22, 3, 25, 0, 0)" }, { "v": 1.429, "f": "1.429Secs" }] }]
    }
```

It works fine in the Chrome and IE, But when i pass the same data in form of object it works every where expect IE and gives below error,

```
 $scope.chartObject.data = {
        "cols": cols,
        "rows": rows//Not this version JSON.stringify(rows)
    }
```

It gives the error as

> Object doesn't support property or method 'getTimezoneOffset'

This happens in each version of IE ,but works in Edge which is Webkit browser.

Comment: Here is the result `"[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2017, 1, 22, 3, 25, 0, 0)"},{"v":1.429,"f":"1.429Secs"}]}]"` and if i say copy this and paste in place of rows without both double quotes it works. but not with array. The chart requires the array only ,but IE doesn't seem to take it